# using addEventListener on multiple selectors within same html page

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
// count chars in textarea
const textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
const remaining = document.querySelector('.help');

    textareas.forEach ((textarea) => {
        textarea.addEventListener('input', event => {
        const target = event.currentTarget;
        const maxLength = target.getAttribute('maxlength');
        const currentLength = target.value.length;

        if (currentLength >= maxLength) {
            return remaining.innerHTML = ('You have reached the maximum number of characters.');
        }

        remaining.textContent = (`${maxLength - currentLength} characters left`);
    })
})
```

I have a counter that determines number of characters left in a textarea. The above code works on the first textarea in the page but not on the other textarea elements. This is part of a tabbed UI within a single html document.

I'm looking for any pointers, not technical as I'm quite new to js, that will get me looking in the right direction.

Comment: That's because `remaining` only refers to the *first* HTML element that matches the `.help` selector. Does every textarea has its accompanying `.help` element? Show us your markup.

Comment: OK, I see that.

Yes, every textarea has a ```<span class="help"></span>``` that shows the ```remaining``` value.

So how do I pass that value to the correct individual element..?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Does it show the wrong text? Not update? Show in the wrong place?

Comment: I would have thought that was clear in my statement" it works on the first element, but not on the others"....

To make it more clear there is NO Update to the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Terry I now have the following, which seems to work as expected:

```
// count chars in textarea
const textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
const remaining = document.querySelectorAll('.help');

    textareas.forEach ((textarea) => {
        textarea.addEventListener('input', event => {
        const target = event.currentTarget;
        const maxLength = target.getAttribute('maxlength');
        const currentLength = target.value.length;

        remaining.forEach((remaining) => {
            if (currentLength >= maxLength) {
                return remaining.innerHTML = ('You have reached the maximum number of characters.');
            }

            remaining.textContent = (`${maxLength - currentLength} characters left`);
        })
    })
})
```

The counter updates as text is entered in the element. If there is a more concise way of achieving this.... Please let me know.